# HVAC cooling latent capacity versus pints per hour

Tags: hvac, dehumidifier

I'm using this calculator to attempt to size a new heat pump HVAC system ...

https://hvac.betterbuiltnw.com/

It gives required capacity as three numbers (in btu/hr): heating, cooling, latent.  I believe the "cooling" figure refers to "sensible" cooling, and that sensible cooling removes the heat from the air without changing the moisture content, whereas latent cooling dehumidifies the air by causing condensation.

Unfortunately, many of the systems I'm considering do not spec separate figures for sensible and latent cooling.  Instead, they specify "cooling", as well as moisture removal capacity in pints per hour (see the attached spec sheet for an example).

My question: is there a simple conversion between the latent cooling requirement and the pints per hour spec of a heat pump, and if so, what is it ?   (In other words, if the sizing tool is telling me I need 33,300 btu/hr of sensible cooling and 3,900 btu/hr of latent cooling, can the 3-ton AMUG36LMAS system in the spec chart handle it ?)

[image: example spec]

Comment: It looks like the latent heat of a pint of water is about 1000 btu.  So if the sizing tool is saying I need 3,900 btu/hr of latent capacity, and the spec sheet says the system can remove 7 pints/hour, then I'm good to go, right ?

Comment: Is this an answer ?